# Upgraded to Angular 10 from 8 - Cannot assign to read only property 'listName' of object

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, ngrx

I upgraded my Angular project from Angular 8 to Angular 10 today and now I'm receiving the following error when I attempt to edit an input field in a Material Dialog

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'listName' of object '[object Object]'
at SaveListDialogComponent_Template_input_ngModelChange_7_listener (template.html:9)
```

Research online suggested this is to do with NgRx but I don't have this installed in the project

HTML:

```
<form #saveListForm="ngForm" class="save-form" novalidate>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-form-field class="name-input">
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="List Name" id="listName" name="listName"
            [(ngModel)]='list.listName' maxlength="50" required #listName="ngModel">
        <mat-error *ngIf="listName.errors?.required">
            List Name is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="listName.errors?.maxlength">
            Name must be less than 50 characters
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
</form>
```

Component:

```
export class SaveListDialogComponent {

constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SaveListDialogComponent>,
            @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public list: List) {}

onSaveClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.list);
}

onCancelClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
}
}
```

List Interface:

```
export interface List {
  listName: string | null;
  listDescription: string | null;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us `List` interface?

Comment: @yurzui Edited the post with the List interface

Answer (score 1):

See the [runtime check](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks) docs.
You probably edit a store value, which isn't allowed.
You can turn of this runtime check if you'd like.

Comment: I dont have NgRx installed in the project, I tried installing it and setting these checks to false anyway but still no luck

Comment: If you don't have NgRx installed then why tag this question with NgRx?

Comment: Because everything online pointed to this being an NgRx issue - thought perhaps Angular had some sort of dependency on it that I wasnt aware of